# How to control the cargobob and lose the military helicopter

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was doing the cargobob mission with travor. I went to the cargobob and pressed the W key to lift up the chopper. The problem is that I dont really know how to control it. I seem to be able to turn by pressing the A and D keys but I cant move the cargobob forward. The help menu did not display the controls, as i flew in the cargobob before. My question would be, is there a way for me to find the controls to the cargobob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I must disclaim that i havent played gta5 enough to know first hand how to fly the cargobob. All information i'll provide will be information i found on the internet and on gaming.stackexchange.*

Any player in gta5 should be able to review the controls at any time by going to the menu -> options -> controls. If you cant find the controls in game there is a handy spread sheet online [HERE](http://guides.gamepressure.com/gtav/guide.asp?ID=30283) that shows the default controls. (so as long as you havent changed your controls you should be fine).

It looks like you should be able to control the cargobob like a plane. So your controls would be (on the numpad):
[image: Controls]

Now as @Adam_Sroka mention [HERE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138714/use-cargobob-to-carry-vehicles) it does take some skill to land the hook and actually hatch onto cars.

> I have done done this several times. It takes a bit of luck but the
>   general technique I employ involves trying to swing the hook into the
>   car. I have also managed to pick up cars that were not mine from the
>   impound also, although whether or not they were another players or NPC
>   cars I do not know.

I hope this information provides enough grounds for you to find your controls. I cant tell you your specific controls since you may have changed them, if not the spreadsheet should provide enough information.

Comment: Those should be Numpad4-6-8-5, not 4-6-8-5.